# NEST elasticsearch using SourceFeldDecriptor

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I previously implemented an elastic search client which took an array of strings and essientally used them for the fields filter.

However i can't find anything in the documentation to support this and can't find any method/setup in NEST to allow me to do this.

I believe the old code was something akin to:

```
string[] arrayOfFields = new string[] {"t1", "t2"};
var request = new SearchRequest<T>("indexname");
request.Query = new MatchAllQuery(); 
request.Source = new SourceFieldDecriptor().Includes(arrayOfFields);
```

However i'm now unable to find anything akin to this. I specifically want to filter the seaerch based on the arrayOfFields as its a generic and will need to change each time.